unless + hypothetical
I’m trying to use “unless” in an imaginary conditional sentence, as in:

I wouldn’t be saying this unless I were sure of the facts.

Does the sentence imply I am or I am not sure of the facts？

You are saying it, therefore you must be sure.

It means you are sure of the facts. It could be rewritten

I am saying this because I am sure of the facts .

with the same meaning.
It is an example of the general class of statements

X does not happen unless Y is true

Which can also be expressed

If Y is true then X can happen.

Note in either case, X does not have to happen when Y is true. It only becomes a possibility. On the other hand, if Y is false then X will not happen.

Thanks, but how did you get to the conclusion?  Is it hunch？ I've had to do a great deal of thinking before arriving at the conclusion you mentioned,  because the use of "knew" always gives me the wrong feeling that "I don't know."

@ForOU I didn't have to work it out. As a native BrE speaker for the past 80 years I've always known what it means. However I'm going to add a bit more to my answer
